# Tail Bound from Asymptotics of an Estimators

Tags: normal-distribution, normality-assumption, asymptotics, probability-inequalities

Consider an non-parametric estimator for a random variable $X$ is $\hat{X}$.
We know an asymptotic convergence for this estimator, in which
$N^{1/4}\left(\hat{X} - X \right)\rightarrow\mathcal{N}(0,\text{AVAR}(\hat{X}))$.

Can we derive the tail bound from the relation above, i.e. $\mathbb{P}(|\hat{X}|\ge d)\le \text{(sth.)}$? Perhaps, Chebyshev's inequality might be able to rule that out, but it will contain fractions out of the exponential, as, $C\frac{\exp(\text{sth.})}{\text{sth.}}$. Are there any other inequalities that might be able to calculate the tail bound in the expressions as $C \exp(\text{sth.})$?

Comment: are you sure about the convergence rate?

Comment: Yes, this current estimator I am working on is not in optimal convergence rate. I know that usual convergence rate should be $N^{1/2}$, while this is $N^{1/4}$-consistent estimator.